# Change android compose BackdropScaffold appbar content from child screen in its frontLayerContent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My current android application employs jetpack compose for its ui.

the main content of this application is contained within a `androidx.compose.material.BackdropScaffold`.

the `frontLayerContent` of the backdropscaffold is controlled via compose navigation.

i am attempting to dynamically change backdropscaffolds appbar from the composable screens housed in the `frontLayerContent`.

my base `viewmodel` has this stateflow variable:-

```
@AllowedFieldAccess("External clients must not use this field", ReplaceWith("access isActionModeEnabled"))
val internalIsActionModeEnabled = MutableStateFlow(false)

val isActionModeEnabled: StateFlow<Boolean>
    get() = internalIsActionModeEnabled.asStateFlow()
```

when i long click on a list item displayed in one of the child composable screens held in the `frontLayerContent` backdropscaffold, i emit true to `internalIsActionModeEnabled` as follows:-

```
internalIsActionModeEnabled.emit(true)
```

in my composable that declares the entire backdropscaffold i collect as follows:-

```
 val isActionModeEnabled by viewModel.isActionModeEnabled.collectAsState()
```

and then where i declare the backdropscaffold itself

```
BackdropScaffold(
        scaffoldState = backdropScaffoldState,
        gesturesEnabled = false,
        appBar = if (isActionModeEnabled) actionModeBar else myAppBar,
        frontLayerBackgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
        backLayerBackgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface,
        backLayerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSecondary,
        backLayerContent = {
        ...
```

the issue i have is that even though i am `emit`ting `true` the `isActionModeEnabled` value is only ever `false`, its initial value.

where am i NOT thinking in compose?
is it possible to achieve the desired dynamic change to the backdropscaffolding appbar contents employing a mutablestateflow?